# Booleon output to check the formatting of a string via regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

If i have a series of strings in Python 3.x im iterating over, how do i check if they all have the right formatting of 1 letter and 12 numbers following it. I want a booleon output so i can use it in an if statment? Thanks

Comment: You haven't stated a regex flavor / where you're using it, but your regex could be along the lines of `[a-zA-z]{1}[0-9]{12}`, then you just check for a match. If so, boolean is true...

Answer (score 0):

```
/[a-zA-Z]\d{12}/.test(string)
```

`[a-zA-Z]` matches any single letter capital or small

`\d{12}` matches 12 digits

and `test()` function returns true if a match is found